# Ubuntu higher cpu usage than in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

So, I've always been a Windows user, and a die hard Windows fanboy. (enjoying pc gaming).
recently I've been trying Linux, Ubuntu and Kubuntu. And I must say, I'm really impressed - I really like it.

I'm having quite a few issues. My CPU usage is constantly extremely high. About 10-20% while not using my computer, and just showing desktop. While viewing a youtube video it's often 70-80%. I am also very often experiencing system errors.

My specs are the following:
Intel i5 3570
ASUS GTX 670
8 GB Kingston RAM
500 GB HDD dualboot with Windows 7.

It's a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Have you installed the nvidia drivers? Is the system up to date( if you find bugs then that may be a solution).

Comment: That's just the way it is. Drivers are huge problem in linux. If you are looking for a new computer, for example, and you want to use linux on it, you are pretty much gambling. Although the chance is higher that everything will work right, you can never know. Nvidia graphics are not well supported. The good thing is, that support is getting better and better, and I hope that in the future, these problems will be almost as rare as in windows. System errors are common, especially if you're not using LTS(ex. 12.04).

Comment: You Tube video due to Flash?

Comment: I have drivers for my GTX 670. Under additional drivers, it was able to detect it. I've also been playing a little Team Fortress 2 on it, but it was extremely slow.

In general my computer is also just slow and laggy. Dragging a window or minimizing it will cause lag.

Comment: @DušanMilosevic : actually I find the nvidia drivers quite well, except for the pre-screen-buffer (I don't remember the name), that allows you to use HD plymouth themes for example. But the performances are good, really good (compared to my old graphic card from AMD-ATI which was awfull under Linux)

Comment: How many driver options were there? You might need to try them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note : This may not be the answer you're looking for, but it can be usefull.*

---

Flash is gonna be hard on your CPU, but 80% of an i5 is ... well, a lot. I noticed before that the built-in Flash from Chrome was using more CPU than the external `flash-plugin` in Firefox. But 20% for looking at desktop, it seems too much.

For example, with my AMD AthlonII X4 3.0Ghz, i'm at 2-20% of each core, using full accelerated 1080p desktop, firefox running, terminal and mouse/keyboard activity. All of that, while looking at `top` and `gnome-system-monitor`, which are pretty heavy themselves.

---

***Is it bad if my CPU is loaded ?***

Not specially. I heard once that Linux, compared to other OS, was designed to use the best out of our hardware. That means it's heavier if you have a better hardware.

As storm09f87a said : "Unused CPU cycles are wasted CPU cycles". It is fundamentally true. Keep this in mind

---

***What to do when my CPU activity seems too high ?***

- You can look at your CPU activity with the command `top`, it's a *CLI* program (command-line interface).
- You can also look at it (total and details) with `gnome-system-monitor`, with a *GUI* (graphical user interface)

I, for instance, use the two combined :

[image]

> You can see on this screenshot that `Xorg` takes a lot. But actually,
>   it is because of the mouse activity, not the display itself. You'll
>   also see that the `gnome-system-monitor` is heavy: but you can ignore
>   this, because this program isn't always running.

The point of this, it's to see which process takes your CPU cycles. Sometimes, you can notice a bug, a leak, that is caused by a process that should not use so much power.

You can try then to kill it with the command `killall nameoftheprocess`. If it was necessary for the OS to run, then either it will restart itself, or you'll have to reboot.

You can also seek what program/service is related to this process and reinstall, optimise, or restart it. You can fill a bug report if needed.

---

You can, if you wish, use a tool designed to make Linux more *eco-friendly* on a desktop PC, and save energy on a laptop.

I never tried it on a desktop PC, but from what I've heard, it helps to reduce the temperature of your system and better regulate the hardware. That tool is `TLP` by Linrunner.

" *TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to fulfil your specific requirements.*"

You can install it with these command-lines :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

It will be used on next reboot. You can also manually start it with `sudo tlp start`. You'll find the documentation on [Linrunner's website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html).

---

***I am experiencing system errors...***

Me too, don't worry. Ubuntu has the filthy habit to report every little error, even when it shouldn't (in my opinion) be noticed to the user.

Depending on the errors : if they are regular, where do they come from, if they keep the system to properly work, ... you can desactivate the "error" message. I always do that, because it's a real pain in the *keyboard*.

To desactivate the notifications on every error, use this command-line :

```
sudo sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/default/apport
```

(or pass `enabled=1` to `enable=0` in /etc/default/apport file).

Comment: The problem isn't really the CPU usage being high. I don't really care if it's 0% or 100%, if it just wasn't lagging. Opening programs takes ages, minimizing a window is laggy.

It's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting errors every time you boot, you may just need to clean your crash directory.

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

After a reboot, you should stop getting those annoying error messages. Haven't had an issue since my first boot. Ubuntu 13.10